# Ansible::when:: how to apply 'and' between jinja result and registered variable status

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to run a task when the host IP is in a given network **and** if the task was not already configured, so, I try to do this:

```yaml
when: "{{ ansible_facts['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'] | ansible.utils.reduce_on_network( '172.20.0.0/24' ) }}" and chrony_is_configured is skipped
```

The problem is that I got an error pointing to `and`:

```
The offending line appears to be:

    force: true
  when: "{{ lenght( ansible_facts['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'] | ansible.utils.reduce_on_network( '172.20.0.0/24' ) ) > 0 }}" and ( chrony_is_configured is skipped )
                                                                                                                                   ^ here
```

What is the problem with this Jinja expression containing an `and`?
And more generally, how can I combine with logical operands, outputs of Jinja expressions and status of registered variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#id2):

> The `when` clause is a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces (see `group_by_module`). When you run the task or playbook, Ansible evaluates the test for all hosts.

So, as a Jinja2 expression, everything between two double or single quotes is a string. So, your when statement look like: `'a string'` followed by `and` key word and then another condition to evaluate.

But the when statement is waiting a first condition to evaluate before the and key word statement and after another condition. That is why it failed. Try to not use doubled quotes in your when statement or wrapped all the statement inside.

Try that piece of code instead:

```yaml
- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'] }}"
  when:
    - ansible_facts['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'] | default([]) | ansible.utils.reduce_on_network( '172.20.0.0/24' ) | length > 0
    - chrony_is_configured.skipped
```

Answer (score 3):

Q: ***"In a condition, how can I apply 'and' to the output of a Jinja expression and the status of a registered variable?"***

A: Either create a list of items or explicitly use the operator 'and'. In a [condition](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals), the items of a list create logical conjunction ('and'). For example, declare variables

```yaml
  _network: 172.17.0.0/24
  _network_reduced: "{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses|
                        ansible.utils.reduce_on_network(_network) }}"
```

and register *chrony_is_configured*

```yaml
    - command: echo "chrony is configured"
      register: chrony_is_configured
      when: false
```

See what you got

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          ansible_all_ipv4_addresses: {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}
          _network_reduced: {{ _network_reduced }}
          chrony_is_configured:
            {{ chrony_is_configured|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
```

Gives. For example,

```yaml
  msg: |-
    ansible_all_ipv4_addresses: ['172.17.0.1', '10.1.0.184']
    _network_reduced: ['172.17.0.1']
    chrony_is_configured:
      changed: false
      skip_reason: Conditional result was False
      skipped: true
```

[Test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html) the variables

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          network not empty: {{ _network_reduced|length > 0 }}
          crony is skipped: {{ chrony_is_configured is skipped }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    network not empty: True
    crony is skipped: True
```

and create the condition either as a list of items

```yaml
    - assert:
        that:
          - _network_reduced|length > 0
          - chrony_is_configured is skipped
```

or explicitly with the `and` operator

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: _network_reduced|length > 0 and
              chrony_is_configured is skipped
```

Both options give the same result.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    _network: 172.17.0.0/24
    _network_reduced: "{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses|
                          ansible.utils.reduce_on_network(_network) }}"

  tasks:

    - command: echo "chrony is configured"
      register: chrony_is_configured
      when: false

    - debug:
        msg: |
          ansible_all_ipv4_addresses: {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}
          _network_reduced: {{ _network_reduced }}
          chrony_is_configured:
            {{ chrony_is_configured|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}

    - debug:
        msg: |
          network not empty: {{ _network_reduced|length > 0 }}
          crony is skipped: {{ chrony_is_configured is skipped }}

    - assert:
        that:
          - _network_reduced|length > 0
          - chrony_is_configured is skipped

    - assert:
        that: _network_reduced|length > 0 and
              chrony_is_configured is skipped
```

give

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_all_ipv4_addresses: ['172.17.0.1', '10.1.0.184']
    _network_reduced: ['172.17.0.1']
    chrony_is_configured:
      changed: false
      skip_reason: Conditional result was False
      skipped: true

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    network not empty: True
    crony is skipped: True

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```